# Flink - Grouping query to external system per operator instance while enriching an event

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently writing a streaming application where:

- as an input, I am receiving some alerts from a kafka topic (1 alert is linked to 1 resource, for example 1 alert will be linked to my-router-1 or to my-switch-1 or to my-VM-1 or my-VM-2 or ...)
- I need then to do a query to an external system in order to enrich the alert with some additional information linked to the resource on which the alert is linked

When querying the external system:

- I do not want to do 1 query per alert and not even 1 query per resource
- I rather want to do group queries (1 query for several alerts linked to several resources)
- My idea was to have something like n buffer (n being a small number representing the nb of queries that I will do in parallel), and then for a given time period (let's say 100ms), put all alerts within one of those buffer and at the end of those 100ms, do my n queries in parallel (1 query being responsible for enriching several alerts belonging to several resources).

In Spark, it is something that I would do through a mapPartitions (if I have n partition, then I will do only n queries in parallel to my external system and each query will be for all the alerts received during the micro-batch for one partition).

Now, I am currently looking at Flink and I haven't really found what is the best way of doing such kind of grouping when requesting an external system.

When looking at this kind of use case and especially at asyncio (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html), it seems that it deals with 1 query per key.

For example, I can very easily:

- define the resouce id as a key
- define a processing time window of 100ms
- and then do my query to the external system (synchronously or maybe better asynchrously through the asyncio feature)

But by doing so, I will do 1 query per resource (maybe for several alerts but linked to the same key, ie the same resource).
It is not what I want to do as it will lead to too much queries to the external system.

I've then explored the option of defining a kind of technical key for my requests (something like the hashCode of my resource id % nb of queries I want to perform).

So, if I want to do max 4 queries in parallel, then my key will be something like "resourceId.hashCode % 4".

I was thinking that it was ok, but when looking more deeply to some metrics when running my job, I found that that my queries were not well distributed to my 4 operator instances (only 2 of them were doing something).
It comes for the mechanism used to assign a key to a given operator instance:

```
    public static int assignKeyToParallelOperator(Object key, int maxParallelism, int parallelism) {
    return computeOperatorIndexForKeyGroup(maxParallelism, parallelism, assignToKeyGroup(key, maxParallelism));
}
```

(in my case, parallelism being 4, maxParallelism 128 and my key value in the range [0,4[ ) (in such a context, 2 of my keys goes to operator instance 3 and 2 to operator instance 4) (operator instance 1 and 2 will have nothing to do).
I was thinking that key=0 will go to operator 0, key 1 to operator 1, key 2 to operator 2 and key 3 to operator 3, but it is not the case.

So do you know what will be the best approach to do this kind of grouping while querying an external system ?

ie 1 query per operator instance for all the alerts "received" by this operator instance during the last 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an aggregator function upstream of the async function, where that function (using a timed window) outputs a record with `<resource id><list of alerts to query>`. You'd key the stream by the `<resource id>` ahead of the aggregator, which should then get pipelined to the async function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure to fully understand the proposal. By doing so, I will do 1 query per resource id, no? Here, I want to do 1 query for several resource id and several alerts. I have the feeling that I would need a kind of "per operator instance" window, but I cannot find it. I can find window on keys (window on a keyed stream) and window all (window for all my elements, but in this case the parallelism is 1). I want something in between (a kind of window all but with a parallelism greater than 1).

Comment: Hi @Julien - OK, I see that you want to also query multiple resources. I think my answer on the mailing list (generating a very specific Integer as a partitioning key) should work. But note that for external queries, you want to use an AsyncFunction. So I think (after keying the stream) I'd add a custom FlatMap function that creates a record with N of these `<resource id>, <alert id>` pairs, and then process that in a following AsyncFunction.

Comment: Hi - Yes, your option to generate a very specific integer as a partitioning key will do the job. Thank you for your tip. The discussion can be found here http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/A-quot-per-operator-instance-quot-window-all-td18391.html